# Binance BSC logs API request data failed

Tags: binance-api-client, binance-smart-chain, binance-chain

I am submitting a request for data from the Binanance API as follows:

```
https://api.bscscan.com/api
    ?module=logs
    &action=getLogs
    &fromblock=24726622
    &toBlock=24726632
    &address=0x94084b7a8d80b2c3cc0dccd87cb6ae3cc67d364d
    &topic0=0xddf252ad1be2c89b69c2b068fc378daa952ba7f163c4a11628f55a4df523b3ef
    &apikey=JRYDR6FBWRKY5C8NMZJKFB8GEP1QHFQJQT
```

However, I can't get any data from this URL. I have double-checked, and I know that the parameters are correct.

Here is an example of using Binanace's API, which works well:

```
https://api.bscscan.com/api
   ?module=logs
   &action=getLogs
   &fromBlock=4993830
   &toBlock=4993832
   &address=0xe561479bebee0e606c19bb1973fc4761613e3c42
   &topic0=0xddf252ad1be2c89b69c2b068fc378daa952ba7f163c4a11628f55a4df523b3ef
   &apikey=YourApiKeyToken
```

Why is that working but mine not working?

Comment: Can you elaborate on this: "However, I can't get any data from this URL."? Both seem to return data for me. Also, you should probably refresh your api key and remove it from the post

Answer (score 0):

I would highly suggest using [Postman](https://www.postman.com/), which you can use to quickly test requests. I ran your request, with api-key, through Postman and was able to get a 200 response with data. [See this screenshot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bcos2.jpg)

Please note I blanked out the api key value. I suggest you do the same in your post unless its fake.

I had to remove the line breaks in the code you pasted. Could this possibly be the issue?